# Silly redis implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, redis

This is a silly Redis implementation that handles only three commands: INFO, ECHO, PING.

The implementation is based on streams:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var redis = require('redis')
var split = require('split')
var net = require('net');

var util = require('util');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;



function makeCommand(parts) {
  var parts = _.filter(parts, (_, i) => i % 2 === 1)
  return {
    command: _.first(parts),
    args: _.drop(parts)
  }
}

function CommandParser(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof CommandParser)) {
    return new CommandParser(options)
  }

  Transform.call(this, {readableObjectMode: true})
  this.__counter = 0
  this.__parts = []
}

util.inherits(CommandParser, Transform);

CommandParser.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  var str = chunk.toString('utf-8')
  if(this.__counter == 0) {
    assert(str[0] == '*')
    this.__counter = Number(_.drop(str)) * 2
  } else {
    console.log(this.__counter, str)
    this.__parts.push(str)
    this.__counter--
  }
  if(this.__counter === 0 && !_.isEmpty(this.__parts)) {
    console.log('here')
    var command = makeCommand(this.__parts)
    console.log(command)
    this.push(command)
    this.__parts = []
  }
  done()
};

function CommandProcessor(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof CommandProcessor)) {
    return new CommandProcessor(options)
  }

  Transform.call(this, {writableObjectMode: true})
}

util.inherits(CommandProcessor, Transform);

CommandProcessor.prototype._transform = function(command, encoding, done) {
  switch (command.command) {
    case 'ping':
      done(null, '+pong\r\n')
      break;
    case 'info':
      done(null, '$9\r\nsome info\r\n')
      break;
    case 'echo':
      done(null, `\$${command.args[0].length}\r\n${command.args[0]}\r\n`)
      break;
    default:
      console.log(command)
      assert.fail()
  }
};


var TEST_PORT = 6380

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  var commandParser = new CommandParser()
  var commandProcessor = new CommandProcessor()
  socket
    .pipe(split())
    .pipe(commandParser)
    .pipe(commandProcessor)
    .pipe(socket)
});

server.listen(6380, '127.0.0.1')
```

You can use the standard redis client to work with it. I'm mostly interested in any advice about node streams, but any other ideas are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

`var parts = _.filter(parts, (_, i) => i % 2 === 1)` this looks like a habit from python. I do not recommend shadowing `lodash` in any part of the code, it is harder to read.

Comment: how do you recommend to rewrite the code?

Comment: anything that does not shadow `_` the lodash variable, try:`var parts = _.filter(parts, (e, i) => i % 2 === 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the whole thing by using a library such as [this](https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi).

Your stream, I believe, should be a duplex, one onto which you write command into redis, and read output from redis. For example, sockets are duplex ([`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)).